# Simplifying/fixing a long query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT Delivery.DeliveryNumber,
       DeliveryStatus.StatusName,
       Delivery.PickupDateTime,
       Delivery.DeliveryDateTime,
       Delivery.PackageWeight,
       Delivery.PackageSize,
       Delivery.PickupAddress1,
       CASE
           WHEN Delivery.DeliveryDateTime IS NULL THEN 'Not Delivered'
           WHEN (DATEDIFF(hh, Delivery.PickupDateTime, Delivery.DeliveryDateTime) > 0)
                AND (DATEDIFF(hh, Delivery.PickupDateTime, Delivery.DeliveryDateTime) < 24) THEN 'Delivered 24hrs After Pickup'
           WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd, Delivery.PickupDateTime, Delivery.DeliveryDateTime) = 0) THEN 'Delivered Same Day'
       END AS Status
FROM Delivery
INNER JOIN DeliveryStatus ON Delivery.StatusCode = DeliveryStatus.StatusCode
```

The problem with this query is that Status can now have `NULL` values.. I don't want `Status` to have `NULLs`.

So I tried adding:

`WHERE (Status IS NOT NULL)` but I knew I couldn't do this anyway.. I don't want to do:

```
WHERE CASE
           WHEN Delivery.DeliveryDateTime IS NULL THEN 'Not Delivered'
           WHEN (DATEDIFF(hh, Delivery.PickupDateTime, Delivery.DeliveryDateTime) > 0)
                    AND (DATEDIFF(hh, Delivery.PickupDateTime, Delivery.DeliveryDateTime) < 24) THEN 'Delivered 24hrs After Pickup'
           WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd, Delivery.PickupDateTime, Delivery.DeliveryDateTime) = 0) THEN 'Delivered Same Day'
```

Is there any way to clean up the query?

My assignment was to design a query such that it returns rows satisfying the following conditions:

- Packages that have been picked up for delivery but not delivered yet
- Packages that have been delivered one day after the pickup (less than 24hours)
- Packages that have been delivered on the same day as the day of pickup
- Packages that have been delivered one day before the pickup (within 24 hours)

I think I got the query right. I just need help cleaning it up because it looks dirty. Any ideas?

EDIT: Added entire data structure:

[image]

Comment: What about `COALESCE`?

Comment: Also, I don't think that there are many persons here with ability to guess your data structure

Comment: DAmn,tried to scroll that picture.

Comment: I can't understand : `WHEN (DATEDIFF(hh, Delivery.PickupDateTime, Delivery.DeliveryDateTime) > 0) AND (DATEDIFF(hh, Delivery.PickupDateTime, Delivery.DeliveryDateTime) < 24) THEN 'Delivered 24hrs After Pickup'
                 WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd, Delivery.PickupDateTime, Delivery.DeliveryDateTime) = 0) THEN 'Delivered Same Day'`
because here both logic shows delivery within 24 hours or same day

Comment: I think it is right? It is supposed to show delivery 24 hours after pickuptime and the other case is delivery on the same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is that you don't want to code the same logic twice (once in the where clause and once in the select list). You can solve this with an outer query picking the desired rows from what you already have:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT Delivery.DeliveryNumber,
         DeliveryStatus.StatusName,
         Delivery.PickupDateTime,
         Delivery.DeliveryDateTime,
         Delivery.PackageWeight,
         Delivery.PackageSize,
         Delivery.PickupAddress1,
         CASE
             WHEN Delivery.DeliveryDateTime IS NULL THEN 'Not Delivered'
             WHEN (DATEDIFF(hh, Delivery.PickupDateTime, Delivery.DeliveryDateTime) > 0)
                  AND (DATEDIFF(hh, Delivery.PickupDateTime, Delivery.DeliveryDateTime) < 24) THEN 'Delivered 24hrs After Pickup'
             WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd, Delivery.PickupDateTime, Delivery.DeliveryDateTime) = 0) THEN 'Delivered Same Day'
         END AS Status
  FROM Delivery
  INNER JOIN DeliveryStatus ON Delivery.StatusCode = DeliveryStatus.StatusCode
)
WHERE Status IS NOT NULL;
```